# Getting the selected index of a tree in codename one

Tags: java, tree, codenameone

I am populating a Tree dynamically with database values using a TreeModel. is there any way to fill and map the item with its id..

And is there any way to get the selected Index value of the parent and child of a tree. I can just fill the tree with text alone as i tried

```
String[][]  arr = new String[][] {sBuilding.toArray(new String[sBuilding.size()]), sFloor.toArray(new String[sFloor.size()])};

            model = new TreeModel() {

                public Vector getChildren(Object parent) {

                    if (parent == null) {
                        MainParent = parent;
                        Vector v = new Vector();
                        for (int iter = 0; iter < arr[0].length; iter++) {
                            v.addElement(arr[0][iter]);
                        }
                        return v;
                    }

                    Vector v = new Vector();
                    for (int iter = 0; iter < arr[0].length; iter++) {
                        if (parent == arr[0][iter]) {
                            if (arr.length > iter + 1 && arr[iter + 1] != null) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < arr[iter + 1].length; i++) {
                                    v.addElement(arr[iter + 1][i]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return v;
```

Answer (score 0):

A tree doesn't have an index, it has a path. A tree of Strings is useful for demo purposes but not so much for real life, in real life you would expect to use something like [FileTreeModel](https://code.google.com/p/codenameone/source/browse/trunk/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/components/FileTreeModel.java), which maps to data that is inherently hierarchical.

Because of that you really need the selected value rather than the selected index and that's easily accessible via the tree.

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful to you to use the function `Tree#addLeafListener(com.codename1.ui.events.ActionListener)` so you may know when an element is clicked and get its path. If you want more complex properties you can make yourself a map.